# MASQUERADE and IPTABLES make to work

Tags: iptables

Got problem with IPTABLES, have two type of IPTABLES save file, one is from dedi-server wich i wanted to use, the other is just from my recent Centos installation.

On recent one MASQUERADE works well
On dedi does not work

I am just a noob wheen it comes to firewalls, so i post two files and ask You, guys to help a bit with, correcting dedi iptables to make MASQUERADE works as well.

Thank you!

```
IPTABLES from dedi server
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Jun 19 02:09:31 2012
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [76062:19805877]
:INPUT ACCEPT [74250:19703779]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1811:101749]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [74061:18596265]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [74061:18596265]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 19 02:09:31 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Jun 19 02:09:31 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [450:24602]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [46:2576]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [154:9003]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 ! -d 192.168.0.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 ! -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 19 02:09:31 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Jun 19 02:09:31 2012
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:ASL-ACTIVE-RESPONSE - [0:0]
:ASL-BLACKLIST - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11444 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8447 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8880 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 106 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9008 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9080 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 9522 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9522 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4487 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8/0 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A FORWARD -i lo -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -j DROP 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT 
-A ASL-ACTIVE-RESPONSE -j DROP 
-A ASL-BLACKLIST -j DROP 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 19 02:09:31 2012

IPTABLES from recent install
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Jun 19 11:27:53 2012
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [132014870:94154517348]
:INPUT ACCEPT [32724511:17221418389]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [99177664:76852711851]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [20020311:7695154264]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [119214834:84553729574]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 19 11:27:53 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Jun 19 11:27:53 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [20020284:7695152280]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 4487 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9522 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 9522 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 4487 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9522 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 9522 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 19 11:27:53 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Jun 19 11:27:53 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1974169:150131862]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [163057:11741154]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1599021:106159155]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 19 11:27:53 2012
```

Comment: Can You post ifconfig output and the contents of /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward file ?

Comment: Do you delibrately have different MASQUERADE statements? The top one has more. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Nope, I can do same MASQ statements on both files. Meaning copy/paste, problem i suspect is in blocking/rejecting/forwaring issue in rest of the file. ip_forward file does not have anything inside, 0bytes. sysctrl.conf has, net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1 net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1. As to ifconfig i have eth0, wich is hdcp from ISP, eth1 wich is 192.168.0.1 for other computers in my LAN, and lo wich is 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

If `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` has no output, then your rules in sysctrl.conf are not being applied which is likely a difference in how the distributions handle things.  To ensure ip forwarding is enabled, add this to your /etc/rc.local file:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

or alternatively add (to the same file):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or if you're setting up iptables via a bash script you can pop one of the lines in there instead (and that would probably be better).